# Big O notation: how to prove $4\sqrt{n} + 2n\log_2(n) + 3 = \mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$?

Tags: big-o-notation

I'm following an online course about Complexity and I'm learning a lot of stuff.

I came across a particular exercise and I'm unable to find it out by myself, this is why I'm writing this message here.

The exercise is to prove the following is true:

$4\ \sqrt{n} + 2\ n\log_2(n) + 3 = \mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$

So basically I'm looking for a $k$ and a $n_0$ such as $\forall n \geq n_o: 0 \leq f(n) \leq k\ g(n)$

- $f(n) = 4\ \sqrt{n} + 2\ n\log_2(n) + 3$
- $g(n) = \mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$

I started to do:

1. $4\ \sqrt{n} +2n\log_2(n) + 3 \leq kn\log(n)$
2. Replace $3$ with $3n\log(n)$:  $4\ \sqrt{n} +2n\log_2(n) + 3n\log(n) \leq kn\log(n)$ with $n_0 \geq 10$
3. Replace $\sqrt{n}$ with $n$: $4n +2n\log_2(n) + 3n\log(n) \leq kn\log(n)$ with $n_0 \geq 10$ and $n_0 \geq 1$
4. Replace $4n$ with $4n\log(n)$: $4\ n\log(n) +2n\log_2(n) + 3n\log(n) \leq kn\log(n)$ with $n_0 \geq 10$, $n_0 \geq 1$
5. Update log base: $4\ n\log(n) +\frac{2}{\log(2)}n\log(n) + 3n\log(n) \leq kn\log(n)$ with $n_0 \geq 10$, $n_0 \geq 1$

Therefore

- $n_0 \geq 10$
- $k \geq 4 + \frac{2}{\log(2)} + 3$

Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: First, get the definition right: change $0\ge f(n)\ge k g(n)$ to  $0\le f(n)\le k g(n)$. Then observe that $\sqrt{n}\le n$.

Comment: Ok, I though about that, but can I replace $\sqrt{n}$ with $n$ then ?

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check if it's better now?

Comment: Your bound for $n_0$ can be made lower.

Comment: Could you explain a bit ? I have the feeling that choosing $n_0 = 10$ is indeed not the right bound.
I checked on Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jytdaclfh6

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Ok sorry about that ! Basically the question here was more about the replacements rules in such an equation.
I'm not looking at someone checking my work, I have no work, I'm just doing that on my free time, with just the will to understand, nothing else.

Comment: I see no logical link between your five steps, so nothing that can be checked.

Comment: Going to add more explicative comments, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: "I have the feeling that choosing $n_0=10$ is indeed not the right bound": any bound is valid provided that the inequation is (provably) fulfilled.

Comment: Well, the way to perform the proof is unusual but goes in the right direction. Beware that when you perform a replacement, you need to replace by a non-smaller function. In particular, replacing $n$ by $n\log n$ requires $\log n\ge 1$. IMO, you would make your life easier by showing that every term is $\mathcal O(n\log n)$, independently.

Comment: Hello Yves,

I just updated the post.

I will also add that replacing $1$ with $nlog_k(n)$ means that $n \geq k$.

Thanks for tips, the goal of the online exercice was to find a value for $k$ and $n_0$ and I guess this is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Same can be possible in steps. For $a>1$:
$$4\sqrt{n}<4n\log_a n$$
$$3< 3n\log_a n$$
where $n>a$. Summing up we have
$$\sqrt{n}+2n\log_a n+3<9n\log_a n$$
for $a>1$. As to "right" bound, then such doesn't exist - any bounds are right, if/when they satisfy definition.

Comment: We are dealing with $log_2$ and $log$ here, the bases are different, shouldn't it matter?

Comment: I added the two first equations in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vhoardqgfh
But it seems that $n > 1$ is not correct, am I wrong there?

Comment: You are right. I changed answer to explicit base $a>1$.

Answer (score 1):

If we divide the inequation by $n\lg n$, we get

$$\frac{4}{\sqrt n\lg n}+\frac{3}{n\lg n}+2\le c.$$

By a quick study of the denominators, we can see that the fractions are monotonically decreasing, say for $n\ge n_0=2$ (they are as of $x>1$). Hence any $c$ such that

$$\frac{4}{\sqrt 2\lg 2}+\frac{3}{2\lg 2}+2\le c$$ will do.

[image]

This establishes $\mathcal O(n\lg n)$, which is also $\mathcal O(n\log n)$.

Comment: I don't follow you on this one, from the first line: $\frac{4\sqrt{n}}{nlog(n)} \neq \frac{4}{\sqrt{n}log(n)}$ could you please develop a little bit?

Comment: @PolDellaiera: $\frac{\sqrt n}{n}=\frac1{\sqrt n}$ !

Comment: Oh my. Sorry !!!